# Using Ionic to develop IBM MobileFirst Platform hybrid applications

Tags: ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I have mobile first development studio in my eclipse and by using that I created a new MobileFirst project and hybrid application. Added an Android and IOS environment to the application. I have idea of worklight. Ionic support is added using mobile first 7.1. How to install ionic? I have read many steps using all CLI based. Can any one guide me to install process of ionic.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, or at least easily possible to use Ionic with a MobileFirst Hybrid project that was created in MobileFirst Studio.

Instead you should create a "pure" Cordova application, that uses MobileFirst's SDK.

You can read more on this in the following blog post: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/04/16/an-overview-of-using-the-ionic-framework-with-mobilefirst-hybrid-mobile-applications/

Comment: thnx. I got http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1502_maynard/1502_maynard.html this link. in this also MFP CLI is used to create ionic project. SO this is the only way right using mfp cli?